# grahams scan to implement polygon partition in c#

Tags: c#, polygon

> I am trying to solve polygon partition problem using graham scan
>
> below is the problem statement and input and expected output
>
> I have implemented graham scan logic but i need to display output
>   according to the sets formed and display all the points with indexes;

The first line will contain a single integer  ().
The next  lines will contain two integers  (), denoting a point with coordinates . Note that points are not guaranteed to be distinct.

SAMPLE INPUT

3

0 0

0 1

1 0

On the first line, output a single integer  (), the number of sets in your partition.
On the next  lines, print the elements of the partition. On the -th of these  lines, first print the integer  (), and then  indices of points forming the -th set. Points are numbered starting from . Each index from  to  must appear in exactly one set.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

1

3 1 2 3

> below is the code implemented according to the output mentioned above,
>   how to print for more sets?

```
 private static void convexHull(Point[] points, int N, int set)
    {
        int index = 0;
        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        // There must be at least 3 points
        if (N < 3) return;

        // Initialize Result
        MyStack<Point> hull = new MyStack<Point>(N);

        // Find the leftmost point
        int l = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
            if (points[i].x < points[l].x)
                l = i;


        // Start from leftmost point, keep moving 
        // counterclockwise until reach the start point
        // again. This loop runs O(h) times where h is
        // number of points in result or output.
        int p = l, q;
        do
        {
            // Add current point to result
            hull.push(points[p]);

            // Search for a point 'q' such that 
            // orientation(p, x, q) is counterclockwise 
            // for all points 'x'. The idea is to keep 
            // track of last visited most counterclock-
            // wise point in q. If any point 'i' is more 
            // counterclock-wise than q, then update q.
            q = (p + 1) % N;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                // If i is more counterclockwise than 
                // current q, then update q
                if (orientation(points[p], points[i], points[q])
                                                    == 2)
                    q = i;
            }

            // Now q is the most counterclockwise with
            // respect to p. Set p as q for next iteration, 
            // so that q is added to result 'hull'
            p = q;

        } while (p != l);  // While we don't come to first 

        set += 1;
        var ele = hull.GetAllStackElements();
        foreach (Point pt in ele)
        {
            index += 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(set);
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", index));

        for (int s = 1; s <= index; s++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", s));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

Comment: Homework?  We don't really like doing homework questions on here, but if you can boil all that down to a much more specific problem you'll probably get an answer.

Comment: i have given a quick summary above now